# Force all DNS requests in LAN to be handled by Router

Tags: networking, dns, routing

Right now my Router uses my ISPs DNS settings, but I can still manually enter alternate DNS servers on my PC and DNS requests from my PC bypass my router.

**My question:**
How do I build my network so that the Router is responsible for resolving all the DNS requests coming from devices on the LAN?

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to understand the question. Can you try rephrasing the description of the network setup? Does it currently work for you? What sort of improvements are you hoping for (i.e. better connection speed, or to fix a problem etc)?

Comment: please read question again, concern point is what is the benefits for using dns entry over WAN router while using dns entry over PC allows users to resolve address over internet easily.

Comment: @SirAdelaide tnx, hope this will help me to clear concept.

Comment: *What is the best practice for configuring DNS, over Router or PC*...this part of your question is too subjective and is going to attract close votes.  Your 2nd question however is actually answerable. Consider editing out the first question.

Comment: thanks, improve question if you feel its not subjective. Hoping for best solution.

Answer (score 1):

By default all operating systems are configured to use DNS supplied by the router (be it the router itself or another ip address). You will receive ip address of the preferred DNS server in reply to DHCP lease request (when asking router for ip address). This is the easiest method to ensure that computer will be always able to access some DNS server.

There is no ideal configuration. You can only optimize toward certain goal - for example maximize performance, security or simplicity. Your current configuration is not wrong, however compared to

1. Default (the most simple setup):

   - Some networks use altered DNS response to redirect you to authentication website. If you use external DNS server, you will be unable to access the internet.
   - Your preferred Google DNS server may be blocked by network firewall.
2. Secure setup with encrypted DNS traffic:

   - The network administrator can monitor what domains you visit.
   - You are vulnerable to packet spoofing (DNS poisoning attack).
3. Maximized performance setup:

   - When your internet connection is very slow or when you need to send a lot of DNS queries very fast, it is much faster to contact nearer DNS server than external one which is behind the bottleneck.

**Edit:** Answer to the second question:

It cannot be forced. You can only discourage clients by making it harder to use other DNS. For example by blocking packets on TCP port 43, which are directed to ip addresses outside of your network and not originating from your router. This can be, however, easily defeated by encrypting the DNS and sending it over port which is allowed in your firewall policy.

Comment: "You will receive ip address of the preferred DNS server in reply to DHCP lease request" This is incorrect. A DHCP lease returns a client IP address. It has nothing to do with DNS configuration.

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm pretty sure it is possible and frequently done. You can use DHCP server software to forward preferred DNS server to you DHCP lease clients. Look up options part of DHCP offer message. Even example server setups like this one use it: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/DHCP/x369.html

Comment: @DavidPostill  + it seems pretty logical to me - What would you do if you want to push custom DNS on clients, create custom network protocol?

Comment: No idea. I've never seen DHCP used that way before, not in Windows anyways.

Comment: @DavidPostill not sure about Windows - but i have a suspicion that receiving preferred DNS from router via DHCP offer message is the only way windows clients operate - sure it's the same IP as the router, but that's only because it arrived with DHCP offer.

Comment: Ok. TIL. I can see in the technet ref it's an optional part of the DHCP offer. "Clients can request these DHCP options, and can use the values to set their TCP/IP configurations for the duration of the lease." :)

Comment: @MarekRost  Please have a look at question I try to specify my doubts clearly.

Comment: DNS settings are by default received via DHCP, that’s correct. That’s true for almost all DHCP clients on all platforms, too. However, the DHCP server can provide any address, it could also be `8.8.8.8`, so the first sentence isn’t accurate.

Comment: @anand  I've already outlined the difference between router and pc dns config (question 1). What didn't you understand there?

Comment: @DanielB I'm well aware that any ip can be sent in the dhcp reply. I've changed the sentence, thank you.

Comment: @marek yes I understand the 1st questions answer but still 2nd question is exist

Comment: @daniel what u say when u have static network???